# Flyweight design pattern to create a pool of shared objects

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm trying to understand how a **Flyweight design** pattern is used effectively to **create a pool of shared objects**. The requirement came into picture is due to the performance improvement checklist of a Java EE web based application.

For complex objects that are used frequently, Im considering a pool of recyclable objcts rather than always instantiating new ones.

Please let me now how flyweight design pattern can be used to create  pool of valuable system resources like 
- threads
- database connections
- socket connections etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For resource pooling, you need:

- the **pooled resources** (could be an array or a collection of resources)
- a way to **create the resources** (could be up-front creation of all resources, or lazy creation on-demand)
- **guarded access** to the resources. Resources must be **aquired** and **released** when they are no longer needed. When all resources are occupied, attempting to aquire a resource must **block** until a resource is released.

The aquire-release part can be implemented using a [`Semaphore`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html), where the pool size is the number of permits on the Semaphore. If you follow [the link to the JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html), there's already an example of such a pool:

(code from [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html))

```
class Pool {
   private static final int MAX_AVAILABLE = 100;
   private final Semaphore available = new Semaphore(MAX_AVAILABLE, true);

   public Object getItem() throws InterruptedException {
     available.acquire();
     return getNextAvailableItem();
   }

   public void putItem(Object x) {
     if (markAsUnused(x))
       available.release();
   }

   // Not a particularly efficient data structure; just for demo

   protected Object[] items = ... whatever kinds of items being managed
   protected boolean[] used = new boolean[MAX_AVAILABLE];

   protected synchronized Object getNextAvailableItem() {
     for (int i = 0; i < MAX_AVAILABLE; ++i) {
       if (!used[i]) {
          used[i] = true;
          return items[i];
       }
     }
     return null; // not reached
   }

   protected synchronized boolean markAsUnused(Object item) {
     for (int i = 0; i < MAX_AVAILABLE; ++i) {
       if (item == items[i]) {
          if (used[i]) {
            used[i] = false;
            return true;
          } else
            return false;
       }
     }
     return false;
   }

 }
```

Comment: excellent example peter, Thank you